# What does a comma do in RSpec's expect command?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given this code:

```
expect(exit_code).to eq(0), result
```

I understand what `expect(exit_code).to eq(0)` is supposed to do, but I don't understand what the comma or `result` variable are doing.  Could someone shed some light on that for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize two variables on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002839/initialize-two-variables-on-same-line)

Comment: Which comma are you asking about, the first line or the second?

Comment: On the second line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not so common, but `to` method can accept an additional argument, which is a message displayed, when the example is failed. Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/add9b271ecb1d65f7da5bc8a9dd8c64d81d92303/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb#L48).

Thus, a custom message can be provided with extra information, how to handle the failed spec:

```
expect(exit_code).to(eq(0), "spec failed, because exit_code is 0, please handle it")
```

The second argument, can be also a `proc`:

```
expect(exit_code).to(eq(0), -> { "expected zero, got: #{exit_code}" })
```

Following @Stefan's comment, here's the [documentation](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/customized-message) about customizing failure messages.

Comment: So in this case it would show the contents of the result variable.  Thanks.

Comment: The documentation might be easier to read than the source code: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/customized-message ;-)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev although relying on implementation rather than documented features can result in unreliable code ;-)